# Cannot execute binary file on ubuntu

Tags: unix, ubuntu, binaryfiles

http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/labs.html 
Hi, I have downloaded the datalab from above link. And I would like to use the datalab compiler given by the site.
However, I got the error : binary file cannot be executed.

I have tried sudo or su but still doesn't work.
Is it because of the 64bits/ 32bits problems?

That file is named as dlc. 
And should be used like this ./dlc bits.c 
which check the syntax for my bits.c

Result using file :

```
 timothy@ubuntu:~/Desktop/15-213/datalab-handout$ file dlc dlc: ELF
 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked
 (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

Here is the result after using uname -a :

```
timothy@ubuntu:~/Desktop/15-213/datalab-handout$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-23-generic-pae #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 22:19:09 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about the binary file. Whether its a shell script? a .out file, or something else. Moreover the link you gave requires authentication, hence not everyone can doenload the file and see why how to get it work

Comment: It should be a compiler for c files

Comment: It checks for the syntax in my c file, I'm not sure what file it is..

Comment: what is the output of "file <your executable binary>" command??

Comment: Please type file um.exe or file um (whichever is the name of your binary file).see the output may be this happen bcz of 32 or 64 bit difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please type `file um.exe` or `file um` (whichever is the name of your binary file).

As you can see from the output of file um that you posted, your binary is a 64-bit binary.

32 bit systems cannot run 64 bit binaries.

Comment: @timothy : yes. Only Mac OS can run this kind of files without bit problem. windows and Linux won't.With Windows or Linux you can either run the 64 bit kernel and 64 bit drivers (and run both 64 bit and 32 bit programs) or the 32 bit kernel and 32 bit drivers (and run only 32 bit and 16 bit programs).

Comment: datalab-handout leungtimothy$ file dlc
dlc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped

Comment: datalab-handout leungtimothy$ uname -a
 Kernel Version 11.4.0: Mon Apr  9 19:32:15 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.26.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: @TimothyLeung : As the Mac OS X kernel is a universal binary containing binary code for 32 or 64 bits so it should work but with windows and linux don't. (This worked fine in my case as I faced the same problem before)

Comment: ok.. thank you so much.. bad luck, maybe I should try another pc

Comment: Once try with the latest download of Valgrind for Mac OS.

Comment: macOS Catalina+ dosen't support 32-bit anymore.